# Sum of a column less than a certain value column. Column being VARCHAR2

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

[image: It is using index for only column C4]I need to sum up a column from below example table:

```
C1  C2  C3 C4    
LG1 10  A  1
LG2 4   B  1
LG3 7   C  3
LG4 5   A  1
LG5 2   A  1 
LG6 4   A  1
LG7 7   A  1
LG8 9   D  2
```

I am currently doing:

```
SELECT NVL(SUM(C2),0)
FROM table
WHERE C3 = 'A'
AND C4 = 1 
AND C1 <> LG8;
```

This is pretty fast with a small set of data in table. But as the data grows I am seeing maximum amount of time being taken by this query in the TkProf.
There are indexes on C3, C4 and C1 as well. All of them non unique.
Please help to understand why it is taking so much time and is there a better way of rewriting for this requirement.

[image: TkProf Output]

Comment: How much time is "so much time"?

Comment: It's impossible to answer performance-related question without actual query plan.

Comment: @Littlefoot, for going over a table with 30k records, it is taking around 18mins each for execute and fetch.

Comment: @astentx: added the tkprof snapshot.

Comment: Please post the query plan. tkprof doesn't show what is going on in the query processing and why. For example, it's unclear why so much `execute` count appear

Comment: @astentx: Apologies. Posted explain now.

Comment: Your statistics is stale, because tkprof shows 17k rows while the optimizer expects 119. Gather statistics for the table along with dependent indexes and check again:  `DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(ownname => '<schema>', tabname => '<table>', cascade => true)`

Comment: It is normal process seeing bad inserting after adding data to table, because before inserting your table trying to add 3 different indexes. You need to connect 3 indexes to one or change index by other column, depense on table using.

Comment: @astentx, the gather stats changed the index the optimizer is using but the run time stayed the same.

Comment: @Yeraz_QazaQ, thanks. I tried already with a combined index but it did not help.

Comment: @user1774651, how many rows are in this table?

Comment: Can you provide the output of this?      `SELECT sql_plan_line_id,sql_plan_operation,sql_plan_options,event,MAX(temp_space_allocated) temp,COUNT(*) secs
      FROM gv$active_session_history
     WHERE sql_id = [sqlid from tkprof]
    GROUP BY sql_plan_line_id,sql_plan_operation,sql_plan_options,event
    ORDER BY secs DESC`

Comment: You're executing the query 17,748 times, getting one row each time. The query is fast (33/17764) ~ 2ms. Most of that time is spent fetching the results. Running it lots of times is what's slow.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding a unique row number to each row and using that to do this calculation. This way as every row has a unique 'identity' it becomes easy to pinpoint that and do any further operations.